# ui-performance plugin not working in development mode (Grails)

Tags: performance, grails

Ive applied the ui-performance plugin to my application. Unfortunately it doesnt seem to work when running the application in development mode. For instance my javascript imports are rendered with a "vnull" version.

E.g.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='/manage/js/application__vnull.gz.js'></script>
```

No exceptions are thrown.

I have a standard config

E.g.

```
uiperformance.enabled = true 
uiperformance.keepOriginals = true
```

Im using Grails 1.3.7. Im not sure how to start fault finding for this issue as I have no error output.

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: try running `grails run-app prod`

Comment: Oh and by the way, i can tell you that i just removed UI-performance plugin in my project as it collides with SpringCache plugin. (when using p:dependant.. together with a cached page, then the cached page doesn't contain correct data) instead im using apache2 module mod_pagespeed which i think does all the same performance tweaks as the plugin. heres a link http://code.google.com/p/modpagespeed/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is described in the docs: http://grails.org/plugin/ui-performance

The plugin does its work when building a war, so you need to disable it in dev mode:

```
environments {
   development {
      uiperformance.enabled = false
   }
}
```

You can run `grails prod run-war` to test it locally without explicitly deploying to a server.